# What uses more ink, glossy or semi-gloss (lustre) paper?

Tags: canon, printing, paper

I am trying to setup printing profiles and don't want too many to confuse my wife and kids. We have both Glossy Photo Paper and Lustre Semi-Gloss Photo Paper. I am wondering what should I make the default paper setting be, Glossy or Semi-Gloss?  We have a Canon Pixma MX892 printer.  Basically which setting uses less ink, if that is even possible?

Answer (score 3):

Gloss papers are coated to reduce the amount of ink absorbed compared to matte, so the glossy setting on your printer ought to output less ink.  On matte paper, using the glossy quality setting, you may have washed out blacks and dull colours.